# Issue on Raphael Drawing and Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, raphael

sing Raphel.js and jQuery Ajax I am trying to load some dots (circles) on the map on this [Demo][1] I a have a PHP file call econo.php  which is like :

```
<?PHP
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT x, y  FROM  econo WHERE c_5000=1";
$results = $con->query($query);
$return = array();
if($results) {
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return[] = array((float)$row['x'],(float)$row['y']);
   }
}
$con->close();
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

and return an array of X and Y at [here][2] 
Thing are fine when I added same coordinates to code (hard coded)  like

```
var coords = [[472.428818,542.403733],[498.605015,549.8196469],[466.124603,560.647791],[474.850002,564.3784961],[478.276206,570.2475322],533.166903,632.3917999]]
```

but through Ajax by using this method

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"assets/econo.php",
    data:data,
    success:function(html) {
    coords = html;
    console.log(coords);
    }
    });
```

I am getting a long list of errors on console as:

```
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="[" raphael-min.js:10
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="." raphael-min.js:10
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="," raphael-min.js:10
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="." raphael-min.js:10
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="]" .......
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting JSON, but it isn't being parsed on the client side. It is treated as raw string. Add a `dataType` to tell jQuery to parse the response as JSON. Now you can assume that the argument passed to the success function is your JavaScript array, decoded from the JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"assets/econo.php",
    data:data,
    dataType : 'json', // <-- here
    success:function(data) {
        coords = data;
        console.log(coords);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks MrCode it is working now, can you please also let me know how come I am not able to pass data from browser to server too? I mean the reason that I removed this was I am not able to query database based  on the user selection

Comment: Passing data to the server should work no problem. Check the content of `data` and add some code in the PHP to collect it.